# A violation of energy conservation?

Tags: general-relativity, energy-conservation, thermal-radiation, stars, redshift

Imagine a universe which contains a single sun and nothing else.

The sum of the energy of the univese is then simply the energy contained in the sun and the photons it emits.
If I have a theoretical sphere centered at the center of the sun from which I measure the energy of the emitted photons,
then the measured energy of the photons should decrease depending on the radius of the measurement sphere because of gravitational redshift.

Then where did the energy of the photons go?

I believe it might just be a relativistic phenomenon or that the decreased energy is accounted for by potential gravitational energy. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, energy of the photons decreases because their potential energy increases. This is basically the reason behind gravitational redshift. If it is hard to think this way about photons, try thinking about massive particles in the solar wind (like electrons) - they experience gravitational attraction in the usual Newtonian sense and naturally their kinetic energy decreases as they travel further from the Sun.

Comment: Alright, thanks! But i want to fully understand. Lets say i have a perfectly efficient dyson shpere around this sun which would convert the cosmic rays and photons into energy and store it in a battery. If i double the radius of the shpere i should get less energy due to the redshift. So where did the rest of the energy go? Is it still stored it at sun somehow as potential energy?

Comment: This energy is part of your battery potential energy. Due to the mass-energy relation a charged battery is slightly heavier than a non-charged battery. So if you charged the battery at $R$ and then moved it to $2R$, you would need to spend a bit extra energy on this movement compared to moving non-charged battery. So at the end at $2R$ you have exactly the same energy balance as if you charged the battery at $2R$ (assuming no energy losses).